# HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, cosmos

I developed a project using asp.net core MVC and cosmos db. When I try to post the form I got

> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request
>   error.

I debug it using break point.

```
 await 'client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("HRDB", "EmployeesCollection"), employee);'
```

Above link so me the error. please help me to fix it .

code:

```html
' [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> AddEmployee(Employee employee)


       {

            await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("HRDB", "EmployeesCollection"), employee);

            return RedirectToAction("Employees");
        }'
```

Error :

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you paste the complete code and error

Comment: A generic exception like that usually means there was an issue reaching the host at all. Check the URL you're connecting to, and ensure that it's not beling blocked by corporate firewalls or such.

Comment: URL is not secure . i run it as unsafe one

Comment: Double check the Uri you are using to connect to the Cosmos DB account. Is it a live account? Is it the Emulator?

Comment: live account cosmos db

Comment: https://github.com/kajasumanie/gittry . full code is here

Answer (score 1):

I  downloaded your code and tried to add an employee ,am getting the same error you are getting.

Below point to check :

- Make sure your URL is correct and Cosmos DB is not blocked as per your org policy.

Here is very simple and very nice article to get started with Azure cosmos DB in web application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-dotnet-application

And finally start adding your model and add it.

Hope it helps.